# Inserting date/timestamp values into SQL Server table using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have three variables stored as number, string and string, as shown below.

```
load_id = 100  
t_date = '2014-06-18'  
p_date = '19-JUN-14 10.51.45.378196'
```

I would like to insert them into a SQL Server table using Python 2.7. The SQL Server table structure is as follows

```
load_id = float  
t_date = date  
p_date = timestamp
```

In Oracle, we tend to use TO_DATE or TO_TIMESTAMP to convert the string to DATE or TIMESTAMP field.

I would like to know how I can do similar conversion while inserting into an SQL Server table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

convert with :

```
import datetime
import calendar
thedate=datetime.datetime.strptime(p_date,'%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f')
thetimestamp=calendar.timegm(thedate.utctimetuple())
```

Answer (score 0):

https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2012/04/18/convert-datetime-to-timestamp

```
DECLARE @DateTimeVariable DATETIME
SELECT @DateTimeVariable = GETDATE()

SELECT @DateTimeVariable AS DateTimeValue,
       CAST(@DateTimeVariable AS TIMESTAMP) AS DateTimeConvertedToTimestampCAST

SELECT CAST(CAST(@DateTimeVariable AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATETIME) AS 
TimestampToDatetime
```

Do the conversion with SQL instead of trying to get Python to match the SQL format.

Neither format matches yours, however the DATETIME type should be adequate.